# Could gets be a loop condition?

Tags: ruby

Wanted to make a loop asking the user for input each time and break the loop as soon as the input is empty.

```
lines << line while line = gets.chomp
```

The code above fails to break the loop. Using the irb and putting in nothing showed that the condition doesn't return a nil:

```
irb(main):001:0> line = gets.chomp

=> ""
```

Is there a way to get it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that in you sample `while` loop will break when `line` is `null`, but `gets.chomp` will return empty string when empty line is given.

Simplest solution to use `loop` with explicit `break`

```
lines = []
loop do 
  line = gets.chomp
  break if line.empty?

  lines << line
end
```

If you would use `ActiveSupport` library(included with Rails) you can do one liner with `presence` method

```
lines << line while line = gets.chomp.presence
```

Comment: You may wish to point out that if this code were to be wrapped in a method one would need `lines` as the last line of the method, following the loop. Better, in that case, would be to write `break lines if line.empty?`. Without Rails you could write, `lines << line until line = gets.chomp.empty?`. In English, is that the crest for the House of Gryffindor?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, your suggestion for one liner will not work becuse `empty?` returns boolean type, so lines will be populated with array of booleans instead of strings.

Comment: I guess I was thinking `lines << line until (line = gets.chomp).empty?` but messed up the execution. (I really dislike those types of economies, btw.)